# ScrollView Custom renderer no longer working on Xamarin Forms 2.x

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, scrollview, custom-renderer

Want to add simple paging to ScrollView.

On iOS it was easy adding a customer renderer like this:

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer (typeof(ScrollView), typeof(JustEat.Ordertracker.Touch.Renderers.ExtendedScrollViewRenderer))]
namespace JustEat.Ordertracker.Touch.Renderers
{
    public class ExtendedScrollViewRenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
    {
          protected override void OnElementChanged (VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
          {
                base.OnElementChanged (e);
                UIScrollView iosScrollView = (UIScrollView)NativeView;
                iosScrollView.PagingEnabled = true;
                iosScrollView.ShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
           }
        }
    }
```

So doesn't look like android has paging flag so was going to implement with touch events or similar, but can't get any events to trigger on Android side. So have tried hooking up events and overriding:

```
 [assembly:ExportRenderer (typeof(ScrollView), typeof(JustEat.Ordertracker.Touch.Renderers.ExtendedScrollViewRenderer))]
 namespace JustEat.Ordertracker.Touch.Renderers
 {
      public class ExtendedScrollViewRenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
      {
          protected override void OnElementChanged (VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
          {
              base.OnElementChanged (e);
              global::Android.Widget.ScrollView droidScrollView = (global::Android.Widget.ScrollView)this;

              droidScrollView.HorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false;

              droidScrollView.Drag += delegate
              {
                    Console.WriteLine("Drag");
              };
        }

       public override bool OnTouchEvent(global::Android.Views.MotionEvent ev)
       {
            Console.WriteLine("OnTouchEvent");
            return base.OnTouchEvent(ev);
       }
    }
}
```

The OnElementChanged definitely gets called as I hit a breakpoint, but the events do nothing, neither does setting HorizontalScrollBarEnabled to false, or even setting .Enabled to false. It's like I have access to a different object?

Found an excellent git repo using same technique to do same thing

https://github.com/chrisriesgo/xamarin-forms-carouselview/issues/24

which works great with 1.x version of forms it uses, but upgrade it to 2.x and it no longer works for above reason.